# How to set automationId to picker item?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

For example, I have the next code:

```
<Picker Title="Example" AutomationId="MyPicker">
   <Picker.ItemsSource>
      <x:String>1</x:String>
      <x:String>2</x:String>
      <x:String>3</x:String>
   </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

How can I set an unique automation id for every picker item?

Answer (score 0):

I think automationId is only for User Interface's Controls, not for its content.
[use-the-automationid-property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/use-the-automationid-property)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't give automation id to every picker item but if you want to select particular item then you can do it using app.Tap()

for eg.
If you want to select the  item 2
then

```
app.Tap("MyPicker");
app.Tap("2");
```

Comment: Is any update available now in 2023 to set automation ids for the picker items